# Angular: Show Text Area Character Count INSIDE the textarea

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, angular7

Angular5: Need to build an application, in which have to show TextArea character count **inside the textarea,** not outside.

Finding numerous ways to show character count, i am able to do that, but Is it possible any how to show that character COUNT **inside** the TextArea ?

Code:
HTML file

```
<td>
<textarea pInputTextArea [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="valueChange(value)" maxlength="1000"></textarea>
<span>{{remainingText}}</span>
 </td>
```

.ts file

```
 valueChange(value) {
  this.remainingText = 1000 - value;
 }
```

Comment: And you must change it with:

..
  this.remainingText = 1000 - value.length;
...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can add container to the textarea with

```
position: relative
```

and then put your counter inside the same relative parent with

```
 position:absolute
```

and control position by `top` and `right` properties.

```
<td>
<div class="textarea-wrapper">
<textarea pInputTextArea [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="valueChange(value)" maxlength="1000"></textarea>
<span class="remaning">{{remainingText}}</span>
</div>
 </td>
```

and in css :

```
.textarea-wrapper {
   position:relative;
}
.remaning {
position:absolute;
bottom: 10px;
right:10px;
}
```

Comment: Hello #YahyaEssam: is it possible you can share any demo, how to implement it

Comment: @Angelina hello, please add your code that makes it outside and I will tell you how to make it inside

Comment: Anyway to include it in table having many number of rows, when table having 1 row  its showing fine, for many rows not showing

Comment: Hi @YahyaEssam pls help my friend amelia on this.. https://stackoverflow.com/q/59468510/12590864

Comment: show only subtraction of number(value) not remaing character like if we enter 3 (only one character the show 997) ....

Answer (score 5):

So You can achieve this with styles.

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9pcwp8?file=src/app/app.component.html)

> HTML

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="desc" class="custom-textarea"></textarea>

<div class="count-div">
    <div *ngIf="desc.length" class="count-text" >{{desc.length}}</div>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
.custom-textarea {
    outline: none;
    resize: none;
    border-right:0;
}

.count-div {
  height: 34px; 
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(169, 169, 169); 
  color: grey; 
  font-size: 14px; 
  border-left:0;
}

.count-text {
  margin-top:15px;
}

.display-flex {
  display: flex
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It must be:

```
value.length
```

Not

```
value
```